# 2018: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together.
To that end, here is how the moderation done here on The Workplace breaks down by activity over the past 12 months:

```
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                 14         18
Users destroyed                                  79          0
Users deleted                                    17          0
Users contacted                                  30          0
User suspensions lifted early                     1          0
Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue            47      3,228
Tasks reviewed³: Reopen Vote queue                6      3,466
Tasks reviewed³: Low Quality Posts queue         25      1,573
Tasks reviewed³: Late Answer queue                0        169
Tasks reviewed³: First Post queue                 3      4,103
Tasks reviewed³: Close Votes queue               49      9,504
Tags merged                                       1          0
Tag synonyms proposed                             1          1
Tag synonyms created                              1          1
Revisions redacted                                2          0
Questions unprotected                             0         27
Questions reopened                               67        189
Questions protected                              94        136
Questions migrated                                5          1
Questions flagged⁴                               22      3,119
Questions closed                                278      2,590
Question flags handled⁴                         915      2,226
Posts unlocked                                    6          7
Posts undeleted                                  16         77
Posts locked                                      6        475
Posts deleted⁵                                  344      2,621
Posts bumped                                      0          8
Escalations to the CM team                       12          0
Comments undeleted                              240          0
Comments flagged                                817      8,230
Comments deleted⁶                            18,131      6,221
Comment flags handled                         8,078        969
Answers flagged                                  61      2,149
Answer flags handled                          1,418        792
All comments on a post moved to chat            425          0
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 3 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 3, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁴ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁵ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁶ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

Wishing you all a happy new year...

Comment: Does "comments undeleted" record the action or the final state?  That is, if I delete some comments, then decide to move the whole thing to chat so I undelete those first and then move them (so the comment ends up deleted), does that undeletion event count in your total?

Comment: Thanks for these stats!  In the future, would it be possible to include # {comments, questions, answers} *posted* to help put these other numbers in perspective?  I know that not all deletions, closures, protections, etc, apply to things posted in the same year, but it'd still give us a rough idea of proportions for these various actions.  (If we *deleted* 24k comments, I'm morbidly curious how many we *got* in the first place...)

Comment: It reflects actions taken, @monica - a comment posted two years ago but deleted and undeleted 20 times yesterday counts as 20 actions apiece. That also kinda confounds normalization, which is why I post normalized closing statistics separately on MSE.

Comment: @TheDarkSide Er, no, that's not correct in any dialect of English I'm familiar with.